# How to expose multiple MEX endpoints from a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding

I have an existing web service and I want it to expose 2 MEX endpoints, one exposed through whatever binding it already has and one through Service Bus Relay Binding. I know how to expose a metadata endpoint from the article here: [MSDN Link for Exposing MEX through SB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706721.aspx)

I need to know how to expose multiple MEX endpoints especially for the scenario that I have and moreover if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this way

```
<endpoint address ="basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCFTest.ISomeContract"/>
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>

 <endpoint name="RelayEndpoint"... />
 <endpoint name="MexEndpoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="default" address="mex" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think so I would need to necessarily add a relay end point.